# How to Export a Shapefile as KML Using R

Tags: shapefile, kml, r, google-earth

All,

I have exported an ESRI shapefile (polygon) to KML using R, but the resulting layer shows only the outer extent of the polygon. 
How can I fill in the area with a color?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

The code is as follows:

```
library(rgdal)
setwd("G:\\GIS_SJR\\GIS Shapefiles\\Boundaries")
polygon <- readOGR(".", "20km_buffer_albers")
polygonWGS <- spTransform(polygon, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84"))  
writeOGR(polygonWGS, dsn="polygonWGS.kml", layer="polygonWGS", driver="KML")
```

Comment: "Limited support is available for fills, line color and other styling attributes" [check their website](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_kml.html)

Comment: I have a similar issue. I am studying this web site, http://gsif.isric.org/doku.php?id=wiki:tutorial_plotkml,  my files are in a raster format.                        try with KML(RAD.all[[100]], file='1998.kml', col=rev(terrain.colors(255)),alpha = 0.5,colNA=NA, maxpixels=100000, blur=2,overwrite=TRUE )

and  plotKML(RAD.all[[100]], colour_scale = rev(c(terrain.colors(255))),alpha = 0.5)

plotKML works better for me

Comment: That web site has soil example too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said in the comments above, the [Global Soil Information Facilities (tutorials)](http://gsif.isric.org/doku.php?id=wiki:tutorial_plotkml) website maintained, amongst others, by some of the **plotKML** authors and contributors gives you everything you need to produce filled polygon areas. In addition to the absolutely correct solution by @Nahm above, here's a reproducible example for future queries on the topic.

```
## required packages
library(rgdal)
library(rworldmap)
library(plotKML)

## shapefile data
data("countriesCoarse")
spy <- subset(countriesCoarse, continent == "Africa")

## plotKML
data("worldgrids_pal")
plotKML(spy["MAP_COLOR"], filename = "africa.kml",
        colour_scale = worldgrids_pal[["lgn3"]])
```

[image: africa]

You may find extra information on further **plotKML** settings including supported color palettes [here](http://plotkml.r-forge.r-project.org/settings.php).